# Mathematic notation and representation of inner product of two vectors when the number of tuples goes infinity

Tags: notation, index-notation

I wondered how to represent the inner product of two vectors, which the index of the vectors starts with N and goes to infinite. The following mathematical expression which I want to express:
$\sum_{i>N}b_i k_i= \mathbf{b}\cdot \mathbf{k}$

As you can see from my expression, I didn't tell the audience that $i$ can go to infinity. Is that any proper way to improve my expression. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your notation is fine, assuming you have provided the audience with the appropriate context. There is a lot of mathematical notation out there, and some of it is overloaded. Expressing ideas clearly with words is a crucial, but often overlooked, part of mathematics. It can make your proofs, papers, etc. much clearer. Words are your friends.

Comment: But, if I insist to show it, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It is honestly pretty clear as written. Assuming that it is clear from context that $i \in \mathbb{N}$, the notation $i > N$ would imply that $i$ ranges over all natural numbers larger than $N$, without terminating at any finite value. If you want to be explicit, you can write $\sum_{i=N+1}^\infty$.